# Do stored procedures in Cosmos DB support JavaScript template strings?

Tags: azure-cosmosdb

Is this usage of **template string** possible in stored procedures and also in the emulator?

```
var the_sql =
    `
    SELECT
        TOP 1 c.uid.number
    FROM c
    WHERE
       c.uid.key.description = "COLA"
    AND
       c.uid.year = 2019
    ORDER BY c.uid.number DESC
    `
```

Answer (score 0):

Template string are OK. Server-side is running JavaScript compatible with ES6, and also supporting async/await (which are from ES7).

Comment: hmm, async is supported on the lang level but I dont think the SDK is ready for it - or can I also do this `var result = await collection.queryDocuments(collectionLink, query)`

Comment: server-side SDK as of current is still callback based but you can use async wrapper, see https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46910406/cosmosdb-stored-procedures-promise-instead-of-callback